# What would be the technical, and wider, implications of a cryptocurrency that used proof-of-disk-space?

Tags: alternatives, storage-footprint

ShelbyMooreIII is promoting AnonyMint and/or AnonyCash as a concept* cryptocurrency based on a disk-space intensive algorithm. Some details are given here: http://anonymint.org/#Proof-of-Work_Designs

What would be the positive or negative impact of this kind of software on:

1. The disk you're running it on
2. The CPU/GPU of the PC
3. The HDD market
4. The environmental effects of increased disk manufacture (I'm assuming here that such a currency would cause an increase in production)
5. Anything else substantially affected

*I don't know what stage of development AnonyMint is at.

Answer (score 1):

I'm speculating here, because I'm not going to test anything out.

1. The [IOPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOPS) would like shoot through the roof. The potentially large amount of writes and reads will likely affect disk life, especially if the disk is an [SSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive). It would generate excess heat. A magnetic disk would also generate constant vibration. Heat can be controlled easier than GPU or CPU heat because there's less of it, and vibration can be dampened using rubber mounts. **The largest risk is simply drive failure due to above average activity.**
2. The GPU would likely be idle. The CPU would only be necessary to drive the hardware operations.
3. I think it may be difficult to get a 3 TB drive for that new gaming rig, because all of the miners would be trying to pack as much disk space into a device as possible.
4. I don't know enough about the manufacturing process to hypothesize accurately.
5. I could see a lot of need for drive recycling. HDDs burn out a lot quicker and take up a lot more waste weight than CPUs and GPUs.

What's interesting about the proof-of-storage-space concept is that it can really take advantage of unused space on consumer devices. I know I've got a 500 GB hard drive in my work computer that has never seen more than 50 GB on it. Amalgamate that across a corporate network, and there's probably PB of space available! I could see malicious types taking advantage of this in malware pretty easily, too: high CPU or GPU usage causes lots of heat and terrible performance, while high HDD usage can just make a program take a few seconds longer to start up.